# How to keep my session alive for the application, when I close it in the tablet

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, cookies, autologin

UPDATE
I have a web app that I can run it on the browser and run it in the touch devices as an application. When I close the browser without logging out, next time I open the page it auto logins. But on the tablet when I close the app (without pressing log out), when I open the app again it asks me for me to log in with email and password.

I am thinking to use modernizr to check for touch event, and on touch I want to save the cookie when closing the app, next log in I want to be able to automatically log in.How to do this on the tablet, what is the difference of browser close and the tablet close

```
 <script>
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                alert('autologin');
              ......Logic here ? .....
            }
            else {
                alert('nothing');
            }
        </script>
```

I have the following code to save the cookie on browser close :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, true);
```

And the expiration time for the cookie :

```
  httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears( 1 );
```

Why my cookies expires

Comment: I"m sure the cookie doesn't expires. Could you check in real browser the cookies with developpers tools like in Chrome with developper tools > Resources > Cookies > Your website? In addition to that, it would be very easy to hack your application if you save the email. You should better to save a token saved in DB !

Comment: Sorry, I double checked on browser it works fine how to fix it on the tablet. I updated the question

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at HTML5 localStorage to keep your session credential saved. That's how we do it for our app.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is check from the browser request if it is mobile:

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

and add the code saving cookies and so on